# Swiperjs in Nextjs always starts with last slide

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I am trying to integrate a slider into my nextjs application using swiperjs.

Here is the sandbox showcasing my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-shadow-0kmz9q?file=/src/styles.css

This is the slider component:

```
const NewsSlider = ({ content }) => {
  // Resize
  const [slides, setSlides] = useState(0);
  const [slideMargin, setSlideMargin] = useState(0);

  const setSlidesSpacing = () => {
    setSlideMargin(
      window.innerWidth <= 500
        ? 30
        : window.innerWidth <= 1000
        ? 60
        : window.innerWidth > 1000
        ? 90
        : 0
    );
  };

  const setSlidesPerview = () => {
    setSlides(
      window.innerWidth <= 500
        ? 1
        : window.innerWidth <= 1000
        ? 2
        : window.innerWidth > 1000
        ? 3
        : 0
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSlidesSpacing();
    setSlidesPerview();
    window.addEventListener("resize", setSlidesPerview);
    window.addEventListener("resize", setSlidesSpacing);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", setSlidesPerview);
      window.removeEventListener("resize", setSlidesSpacing);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <Swiper
          className="swiper"
          modules={[Navigation, Scrollbar, A11y]}
          navigation
          scrollbar
          spaceBetween={slideMargin}
          slidesPerView={slides}
          observer={true}
          observeParents={true}
        >
          <SwiperSlide key={1}>
            <div className="image">
              <img src="/green.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <h2>Slide 1</h2>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide key={2}>
            <div className="image">
              <img src="blue.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide key={3}>
            <div className="image">
              <img src="yellow.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <h2>Slide 3</h2>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide key={4}>
            <div className="image">
              <img src="red.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <h2>Slide 4</h2>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default NewsSlider;
```

Somehow it always starts on the last slide. I would be very thankful for any kind of help!